# Why i get Undefined variable when i use PostController in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

When i use return in Post::find($id); everything was perfect but when i remove the return and add return view('posts.show')->with('post', $post); that give me the Undefined variable: post Error

In PostsController File:

```
public function show($id)
{
    Post::find($id);
     view('posts.show')->with('post', $post);
}
```

---

In Post.php File:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Post extends Model
{
    // Table Name
    protected $table = 'posts';

    // Primary Key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    // Timestamp 
    public $timestamps = true;

    const CREATED_AT = 'creation_date';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'last_update';
}
```

---

In show.blade.php File:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<h1>{{$posts->title}}</h1>
<small>Written on {{$post->created_at}}</small>
@endsection
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing wrong in controller. If you want to return a variable to the view you have to define it first. So it should like

```
public function show($id)

{

    $post = Post::find($id);
    return view('posts.show')->with('post', $post);
}
```

Comment: i also do some mistake on show,blade.php. The mistake was <h1>{{$posts->title}}</h1> and i select $posts for postController.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't creating the variable at all. In your controller, first set the variable:

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    return view('posts.show')->with('post', $post);
}
```

Also correct typos in your views. You are using `$posts` variable but it should be `$post` as you are passing the variable `$post` to the view, not `$posts`;

Answer (score 0):

You are just fetching the value . So you have to assign it to a variable and then pass it to the view like below

```
$variableName=Post::find($id);
     view('posts.show')->with('post', $variableName);
```